# To use sudo feature, what should I wrote in the my application?

Tags: android, sudo

To use sudo feature, what should I write in the my application? Should I write something? If yes, can you tell me how I can write sudo application? Do I need to change manifest.xml, or add some Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the device is rooted and your app has been granted superuser permissions, you can use the following method to run commands as root:

```
public static void runAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());  
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
                String test;
                while((test = bf.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, test);
                }
            }

            //os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Just pass it a list of commands in a String array.

Comment: ' your app has been granted superuser permissions' how ?

Comment: Normally, on a rooted device a dialog will popup asking the user whether or not this app should be given root access. The user must agree to give you access.

Comment: List of the command supported by the Android device by default .

Comment: There is a pretty complete list [here](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference)